# Planescape Torment: Joining the Anarchists: How to kill Sandoz?

Tags: planescape-torment

I want to join the Anarchists and the second task is to kill Sandoz. Bedai-Lihn says I should not worry about the guards, but as soon as I kill Sandoz all the Godsmen get hostile. When I return to Bedai-Lihn she says "Away with you! I have no time for such as you" and my only answers are "Attack her!" or "Leave".

What's the proper way to solve this quest?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I played that part. But it rang a bell, so I digged and found [these](http://www.sorcerers.net/Games/Torment/Walkthrough/act5-findravel/findravel-foundry.php) [two](http://www.pahnation.com/planescape-torment-walkthrough-how-to-join-anarchists/) walkthroughs.

The short/non-spoiler version is: you'll have **two** interactions with Sandoz. And due to some oversight/bug/whatever they have to be done in a specific order. Otherwise, guards get hostile even though the narrative says they shouldn't.

The spoiler version:

> Before completing the Anarchists' quest, you're supposed to have finished the one where you actually save Sandoz (prevent him from killing himself), which is what you needed to join the Godsmen.
>  I can't tell if you actually *need* to join the Godsmen but I vaguely recall that I had to go back to talk to Keldor before coming back to kill him.

I don't know what happens if:

> You actually convince Sandoz to kill himself and want to join the Anarchists later.

I should point that I haven't tested it recently (and you shouldn't trust my memory too much). It does sound *very* familiar, though.

I'm pretty sure that's the way I solved it.